# Console not writing

Tags: c#, string, console

```
using System;
using System.Net;
static class Program {
    public static void Main()
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        var proxies = wc.DownloadString(@"http://proxy-ip-list.com/download/free-proxy-list.txt");
        Console.WriteLine("http://" + proxies.Split(';')[5]);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

[image]

I'm very much baffled...

I tried printer Char-by-Char.
I tried assigning the string to a variable before writing.
I've tried everything, what's going on?

`Console.WriteLine("http://" + "182.255.46.123:8080");` works...

Comment: I ran this exact code. Works fine on my end. Prints the 5th proxy on the list....

Comment: *With* the `HTTP` prefix?

Comment: Yup. I ran it without the Console.ReadLine(), though.

Comment: Wow, you must be a quick reader

Comment: I used an online C# compiler, so it didn't actually use the Command Prompt. It seems like it also filters out the special character outlined in the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the string being returned contains a carriage-return character at the beginning:

```
proxies.Split(';')[5] = " \r182.255.46.123:8080"
```

You can remove it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("http://" + proxies.Split(';')[5].Replace("\r", "").Trim());
```

Comment: Do we really need 'Replace("\r", "")'? Just Trim() will be enough - which will remove all white spaces from start and end.

Comment: Technically, `Trim` will remove all whitespace characters, including the "`\r`". This was just to be explicit for the example. And, I suppose, if the "`\r`" was after a non-whitespace character. :)

Comment: Thank you, Rufus for the quick details... :-)

Comment: I did end up using trim, only*

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer as per your comment. You just need to Trim() to remove all white spaces from start and end.

```
using System;
using System.Net;

static class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        var proxies = wc.DownloadString(@"http://proxy-ip-list.com/download/free-proxy-list.txt");

        Console.WriteLine("http://" + proxies.Split(';')[5].Trim());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not what I'm trying to do. I want `http://182.255.46.123:8080` printed, only.

Comment: Sorry, your question was not clear initially, I thought you want to print everything. From the list of IPs, you want to print always the first one? First one is from Austria and the second one is without any country.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Net;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            var proxies = wc.DownloadString(@"http://proxy-ip-list.com/download/free-proxy-list.txt");
            var regex = new Regex(@"\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}:\d{1,5}");
            var match = regex.Matches(proxies);
            Console.WriteLine("http://" + match[3].Value);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Is most save in case of changes in content of the request result.